# Apache Camel unmarshalling data

Tags: java, apache-camel

Can anyone help me to write spring dsl unmarshal. In my interface I have

```
org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.SoapJaxbDataFormat soapJaxbDataFormat = ....
```

How can I use it in spring dsl, maybe with `<simple>`. like in case with constants and enums.

Comment: Why do you want to use the spring dsl? I don't think it is maintained anymore. Either use the java dsl or blueprint.

Comment: That is wrong, spring dsl is certainly supported. Its only on OSGi its not, because spring-dm is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the camel-soap documentation where there is a little example for XML DSL: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-soap/src/main/docs/soapjaxb-dataformat.adoc

You can also find some example from the unit test of camel-soap: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-soap/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/dataformat/soap

Comment: unmarshalling of XMLGregorianCalendar using camel, SoapJaxbDataFormat is null, any idea how I should get exact value set in object before unmarshalling ?